# В jar не запаковались изображения (или он их не видит)

Tags: java, отладка, jar, awt

Изображение находится в папке src. Пока запускаю не jar всё работает, изображение считывается, но если запускаю jar, то изображение не загружается, null pointer exception.

```
try {

            URL resource = Sticker.class.getResource("\\transparentSticker.png");
            img = null;
            this.img = ImageIO.read(Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile());
            System.out.println("c");
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
        }
```

Пробовала использовать intputStream, но когда пытаюсь, то даже не в jar не работает

```
      InputStream input = Sticker.class.getResourceAsStream("\\transparentSticker.png");
        if (input == null) {
          
            input = Sticker.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("\\transparentSticker.png");
        }
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы изображение загружалось?

---

Сейчас код выглядит так, но всё равно не работает, FileSystemNotFoundException...  Вариант "/transparentSticker.png" не помогает. "\resourses\transparentSticker.png" тоже. Так оно даже при запуске в Intellij-Idea не работает, не то что при запуске файла jar
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая проблема это \\. Нужно заменить на `/`. Далее, не ясно из вопроса как именно вы создаете jar. Проверьте, что файл добавился в jar (просто откройте jar файл zip-ом, это обычный архив, файл должен быть в корне архива)

Comment: Я делаю jar в intellij-idea так: задаю файл с функцией main в структуре проекта, потом в меню build выбираю build artefacts. Сам jar открывается, в нём работает всё кроме изображений.

Comment: А зачем вы дёргает класслоадер? Вы что, думаете, что это поможет?

Comment: Да, думала. Смотрела другие похожие вопросы, там дёргали. Но мне не помогает, как только запускаю jar ихображения грузиться перестают. Но если запускаю сам проект в IDE, то первый вариант кода работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream in = Sticker.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("transparentSticker.png");
```

Если файл лежит в ресурсах. Так же, если папка ресурса была назначена раньше чем вы туда положили файл, нужно снять метку и поставить её заново.

И поток закрыть не забудьте )

Answer (score 0):

1. Создайте в структуре проекта директорию resources и положите туда изображение.
2. Замените \\transparentSticker.png на /transparentSticker.png.

Comment: Так? ``` URL resource = getClass().getResource("/transparentSticker.png");``` NullPointerException даже если запускаю не jar(

Comment: Да. Вы положили файл в src/main/resources?

Comment: Папка resourses должна быть внутри src? Можно скриншот примера куда что добавлять?

Comment: Просто в src/resourses, отредактировала вопрос, чтобы показать

Comment: Изображения, файлы с расширениями .txt, .csv и другие в основном кладутся в папку resources. Если ваш проект расположен по пути src/main/java/..., то папка с ресурсами в основном располагается по пути scr/main/resources.

Comment: @IlnurGibadullin все верно пишет, только не стоить забывать о настройках проекта. IDEA должна знать что является папкой с ресурсами.

Comment: Судя по добавленному скриншоту, вы хотите работать с изображением прямо при конструкторе класса и ошибка говорит, что classLoader, который загружает класс еще не нашел ресурс. Рекомендую работать с ресурсами в методе класса, а не в конструкторе, тогда ошибки не будет.